# Перенос большой БД за несколько раз

Tags: postgresql

Использую postgres. Имеется несколько баз данных, необходимо перенести все, кроме нескольких таблиц с логами и историей. Так же архивирование и восстановление бд может производиться в определенное время, несколько часов в день. Функция backup из интерфейса pgadmin видимо не подходит, она все и разом архивирует. Из идей как произвести перенос, пока что реализация скрипта на питоне, который сперва скопирует схему баз данных и таблиц, а затем на протяжении недели будет копировать записи таблиц и файлы с жесткого диска. Может есть какие то встроенные функции для этого дела?

Comment: `pg_dump --exclude-table=... > dump.sql`

Comment: 1 источник остановить затарить 2 источник(( сервер перенести и растарить .... ОЧЧ быстро ....

Comment: @nörbörnën а можно эту команду выполнить не за раз?

Comment: можно сделать несколько дампов, разделив их по наименованиям таблиц `-t`

Comment: я думаю в таком случае связи порушатся и не понятно как схемы с их настройками тогда копировать

Comment: как из вариантов использовать навикат как прокладку. в нем есть источник, приемник, какие об екты переносить и расписания. из минусов навикат компютер должен быть включен. еще как вариант смотреть с СЛАВЕ серверами ... ( репликой основного...